# Ignore newline in LaTeX variable

Tags: tex-core

I have some string in variable `\somevar`, eg. `foo\\bar`. How can I force LaTeX to ignore newline in `\somevar`. When I write content of the variable there should be

```
foo bar
```

and not

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: Why do you store a newline in your variable if you don't want to display it? Maybe you need to make a wrapper around your macro to split the usage?

Comment: The variable is in document class. Content of the variable comes from user's document and user can put newlines there. One time I can print the variable with newline and another time the newlines are not acceptable but this is still the same text.

Comment: How about providing an option like `\chapter` does? You can write `\chapter[alternative title]{title}` where one can have newlines and the other can't.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Within the group that you are expanding the macro you can do

```
\let\\=\relax
```

This will temporarily neuter the effect of `\\`.